# ¿ Cómo mantener los mismos valores que se tiene en el método de una clase después de manipular los datos en otras clases?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo un problema con el manejo de objeto clase en java,
tengo una clase llamado Pedido_detalle.java

```
public class Pedido_detalle{
    private String nro_pedido;
    private String codpro;
    private int cantidad;

    public void setNro_pedido(String nro_pedido){ this.nro_pedido= nro_pedido;}
    public void setCodpro(String codpro){ this.codpro= codpro;}
    public void setCantidad(int cantidad){ this.cantidad= cantidad;}

    public String getNro_pedido(){ return this.nro_pedido;}
    public String getCodpro(){ return this.codpro;}
    public int getCantidad(){ return this.cantidad;}
}
```

El otro archivo Compras.java.

```
public class Compras{

   public void Addcompras(){
      Pedido_detalle pdetalle new Pedido_detalle ();
      pdetalle.setNro_pedido("00010");//Valor original
      pdetalle.setCodpro("0044");//Valor original
      pdetalle.setCantidad(10); //Valor original

      System.out.println(" paso1-> cantidad ORIGINAL es: "+pdetalle.getCantidad);// Salida 10
      ManipulacionPrueba(pdetalle);
      System.out.println(" paso2-> cantidad ORIGINAL es: "+pdetalle.getCantidad);
      // Salida 20,  ¿PORQUE 20?, deberia ser 10 
   }
    public void ManipulacionPrueba(final Pedido_detalle pdetalle2){
          //Cambiamos el valor del atributo cantidad;
          if(pdetalle2.getNro_pedido.equals("00010")){
                pdetalle2.setCantidad(20);
         }
    //el objeto pdetalle2 se utiliza para otros fines

   }
}
```

Problema en el archivo Compras.java método Addcompras();
¿Porqué el objeto pdetalle no mantiene los mismos valores que se tiene en el método Addcompras() despues de llamar al método ManipulacionPrueba()?, el objetivo es que no se cambie sus valores. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?.Espero su ayuda, gracias por leer mi pregunta

Comment: No se entiende lo que queres hacer. Cómo el objeto va a mantener los mismos valores después de ejecutar `ManipulacionPrueba()` cuando este método cambia el valor `cantidad`. Creo que no comprendes como funcionan los métodos. `ManipulacionPrueba()` funciona así: dice pasame un objeto por parámetro de tipo `Pedido_detalle` y si su `nro_pedido` es igual a `00010` cambiale el valor de `cantidad` a `20`. Por eso es que te cambia el valor `cantidad`

Answer (score 0):

Primero comentarte que esta linea la tienes mal, no se si habra sido al copiar el codigo aqui en la web

```
 Pedido_detalle pdetalle new Pedido_detalle ();
```

Deberia ser asi

```
  Pedido_detalle pdetalle= new Pedido_detalle ();
```

Aparte de esto, creo que el problema es de concepto sobre programacion orientada a objectos y sobre el ambito de variables.

Lo primero, es que trabajas con dos objectos,y cada objecto es diferente entre si, es como si fuesen dos personas, las personas tienen ojos, pero una persona los puede tener de color azul y otra de color verde, pero aparte de esto, tienes un problema de ambito de variables y objectos

tu creas la variable (ademas del objecto) **pdetalle** dentro de **AddCompras** por lo tanto dicha variable que guarda el objecto creado solo sera valida dentro de ese metodo , es decir su ambito es local dentro del metodo AddCompras(), por lo tanto ,el objecto fuera del metodo no existe, si quieres que dicha variable y  objecto, sea accesible por todos los metodos, debes crear la variable fuera de cualquier metodo , es decir, crear una variable global.

Algo parecido a esto

```
public class Compras{

Pedido_detalle pdetalle;

  public void Addcompras(){

      pdetalle= new Pedido_detalle ();
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es el clásico ejemplo que viene de la mano con la pregunta **¿Java trabaja por valor o por referencia?**

El problema que tenes es el siguiente. Vos estás enviando al método "ManipulacionPrueba", la variable "pdetalle", cambiando el nombre del argumento a "pdetalle2", y suponiendo que ahora estás trabajando con una variable nueva.

Entonces, ¿por qué al realizar el siguiente set

```
 if(pdetalle2.getNro_pedido.equals("00010")){
       pdetalle2.setCantidad(20);
   }
```

también modificamos el pdetalle?

Sencillo: porque Java pone en el argumento del método, **la dirección de la memoria del objeto creado en el heap**

Eso significa, que si vos hicieras

```
(pdetalle2 == pdetalle)
```

Java te diría que son iguales, porque literalmente lo son. Ambos están en la misma dirección de memoria. Es decir, son lo mismo.

¿Cuál sería la solución para poder seguir trabajando con pdetalle2 cómo un objeto aparte?

Deberías hacer, apenas ingresas el método "ManipulacionPrueba":

```
Pedido_detalle pd2 = new Pedido_detalle();
pd2.setNro_pedido(pdetalle2.getNro_pedido());
pd2.setCodpro(pdetalle2.getCodpro());
pd2.setCantidad(pdetalle2.getCantidad());
```

Espero que haya quedado claro porque tenes que hacerlo de esta manera (En realidad, lo ideal sería realizar un mapper, pero para este caso lo estoy haciendo tácito para que se entienda lo más claro posible).

Answer (score -1):

Primero que nada en primer punto en el método addCompras no estás asignando valor al atributo Cantidad, solo se está asignando a Nro_pedidos. Lo segundo es que en el metodo ManipulacionPrueba solo está usando la referencia del objeto de Pedido, lo que puedes hacer es recibir en el método ManipulacionPrueba solo el valor a validar y dentro de este mismo método crear una nueva instancia de Pedido si es que necesitas usar en este mismo método el valor cantidad.

Saludos.